# Encoding mpeg-1 video with iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ffmpeg

I'm looking for a way to convert videos recorded with the device camera into the original mpeg-1 video format + and mp3 file - on the device itself.

I know this seems a bit strange but I have some good reasons why I want to do this.

Is this even possible? Are there any frameworks that can make this easier?

I believe ffmpeg might be a possibility but I've also heard there are patent & licensing issues with using it.

Answer (score 1):

use ffmpeg , there you have code for conversion , build the ffmpeg for iOS and use the libs write your own custom code which interface with ffmpeg

Comment: I've read that using ffmpeg will mean apple don't accept the code because of the ffmpeg license

Comment: See ffmpeg is used by many popular apps in App Store , don't worry..But don't tell app that I am using it lol :)